# node.js mongodb express - cannot POST/

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoUtils = require('./mongooseData.js')

var app = express();

app.get('/businesses' , mongoUtils.findAllBusinesses);
app.post('/newBusiness' , mongoUtils.enterNewBusiness);

app.listen(3000);
```

this is the server, i dont know why but the GET is working but the POST isn't,

i tried with the commandprompt (curl -X POST localhost... -d ... )
and with the chrome extention REST

and i still getting the Cannot POST/

the reply from the node server is "OK" and printing to the console

Comment: What is the HTTP status code returned by express?

Comment: the status code is 404

Comment: `Cannot POST /` means it's POSTing to `/`. Are you sure your form has the correct route?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you are not processing the response properly.

I tried this and worked (with express 4.8.5):

```
var express = require('express');
var log = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Logging');
    res.end();
};

var app = express();

app.get('/businesses' , log);
app.post('/newBusiness' , log);

app.listen(3000);
```

and got:

```
$ curl -i localhost:3000/businesses
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
ETag: W/"0-0"
Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 12:45:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -X POST -i localhost:3000/newBusiness
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 12:45:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Make sure that you have `res.send`, `res.end`, `res.status` or similar.